# Info from api received, no result on the page by {{value_expression}}

Tags: angular, typescript, api, drupal

Hi and thank you in advanced,

I have a issue regarding {{ value_expression }}. I'll running a small application which using a REST api from Drupal 9. My list component works just fine but when I click further to my detailpage I wont receive any information, however when I use {{ object|json }} it is outputting the whole (related to the coin url, see example) api, so it is receiving its data.

What I use:

- Angular 10
- Drupal 9

example json pipe {{ ico | json }}

```
[ { "title": "Coin", "body": "<p>This is just the description about the Coin project</p>\r\n", "field_coin_uri": "name-of-coin", "field_coin_symbol": "SYMB" } ]
```

Data.service.ts:

```
getIcoDetail(field_coin_uri: string) : Observable<Icos> {
    const url = `${this.ApiUrl}/coins/${field_coin_uri}`;
    
    return this.http.get<Icos>(url);
  }
```

detail.component.ts:

```
export class IcoDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  ico: Icos;
  
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private dataService: dataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    const field_coin_uri = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('field_coin_uri');
    console.log(field_coin_uri);

    this.dataService.getIcoDetail(field_coin_uri).subscribe( ico => this.ico = ico );
  }

}
```

detail.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="ico">
    {{ ico|json }}
    <h3>{{ ico.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ ico.body }}</p>
</div>
```

If there is any information needed for answer my question, please let me know, I will provide you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are receiving from API is an array. You need to access it using the index values and check if the following works.

```
this.dataService.getIcoDetail(field_coin_uri).subscribe( ico => this.ico = ico[0] );
```

Comment: You literally make my day, I search a lot on the internet but couldn't find out why, followed some tutorials on how to but nobody used the index value. Thank you so much.

Comment: @dutchsociety Happy to help :)

Comment: @PrincelsNinja is there any change you can take a look at my other issue as well?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63580438/angular-mergemap-coin-information-from-cms-and-price-stats-from-other-api?noredirect=1

Would much apreciated :).